# How to count number of words in a string?

Tags: c++, string

I have prompted the user to input a string in the main function in my program and store it `userString`, and want to display how many words there are.

This is the function I intend to call from main:

```
int countWords(string d) {
    string words = " ";
    for (int e = 0; e < d.length(); e++) {
        if (isspace(d[e])) {
            cout << "The string " << words << "word(s). ";
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

I read somewhere that the function should actually count the number of white spaces (which is why I used `isspace()`), and not the words themselves.

How do I go about counting the number of words there are in the string and displaying it in the same function?  I am having trouble figuring it out and I'm getting errors.

I also cannot use library functions.

Expected output:

- The string "2020" has one word.
- The string "Hello guys" has two words.

Comment: I suggest you add an `int count = 0;` atop your function, then work through your own examples (and perhaps a couple more) on paper while imagining what should happen to `count` as you encounter each value of `d[e]`.  If you're not sure how to express that in code, then that'd be a better question, but I'm sure you can work out some logic/algorithm for how a person would work out the number of words, and I don't see any attempt to express than in your current code.  Hint: you may find yourself interested in transitions from space to letters & back (i.e. `isspace(d[e]) && !isspace(d[e-1])`.

Comment: your function doesn't do any counting and just output spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use boost, a simple for loop will do.

```
#include <cctype>

...

for(int i = 0; i < toParse.length(); i++){
    if (isblank(toParse[i])){
        //start new word
    }
    else if (toParse[i] == '.'){
        //start new sentence
    }
    else if (isalphanum(toParse[i])){
        //add to your current word
    }
}
```

**edit:**  you can just increment an integer where you see the `//start new word.`

Answer (score 0):

try `boost::split()`, which will put words into a vector

Comment: use a library just to get the number of words? don't you think that will cause too much overhead?

Comment: I am not allowed to use library functions, I will get points off the assignment if i do.

Comment: Not even close. I have done the majority part of it. I'm having trouble with this function is all. How did I ever imply that I wanted you to do my homework? I need help, is this not what this forum is intended for?

Comment: Use existing lib or not. It is up to you. You may noticed the function is called from main(), sounds like some informal projects. To be productive, if the performance isn't in question, I think using a lib is not a bad idea. Just avoid reinventing wheels. My 2 cents. However, I will post some code if no libs are allowed.

Comment: `I'm having trouble with this function is all` what trouble?

Comment: @LeandroBattochio, let's keep the attitude positive and just focus on what it takes for SO to help answer the question.  If you're not inclined to help, look at other questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to count something in a range satisfying some condition, you can think in [std::count_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/)

Example:

```
int countWords(std::string d) 
{
    int w = std::count_if(d.begin(), d.end(), [](char ch) { return isspace(ch); });
    std::cout << "The string \"" << d << "\" has " << w + 1 << " words." << '\n';
    return w;
}
```